# Javascript Touchmove takes intial point from <body> not from element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Javascript's touchmove event taking the Initial point from the `<body>` not from selected division.
how can I make it select its initial point from the selected division?

**Note** on single touch it takes an initial point from selected div but on touchmove it takes from the body.

Here is an example:

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var x = event.touches[0].clientX;
  var y = event.touches[0].clientY;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x + ", " + y;
}
```

```css
.left{
padding:10%;
background-color:#444;
float:left;
display:block;
position:relative;
margin-right:10px;
}
.blue{
padding:10% 30%;
background-color:#00f;
float:left;
display:block;
position:relative;
}
#demo{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<h1>DOM touchmove Event</h1>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="blue" ontouchmove="myFunction(event)"></div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong>Blue is the example for touch devices.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I suppose you've to read the event from [changedTouches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/changedTouches) object. But [`touch.clientX/Y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/clientX) will yet be related to the the viewport.

Comment: @Teemu how can I get touchpoints of particular div, I read the reference provided you but floats above my head.

Comment: You can't get that point directly, you've to calculate it using ex. getBoundingClientRect.

Comment: @Teemu I got it after searching a lot. Thanks for your kind suggestions